# How can I define a hooked arrow with the hook on the bottom, that will work in tikz-cd diagrams?

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

The title says it all, really. I'd like to use an arrow that looks exactly like an "upside down `\hookrightarrow`" in a diagram (for which I'm using `tikz-cd`), but I am really not comfortable enough with the nitty-gritty details of defining arrows that play nice with the extensibility etc. requirements of `tikz-cd` to define such a thing by myself.

More generally, an answer that explains how to edit a pre-existing arrow (or create a new one entirely?!) that will work properly in `tikz-cd` would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the arrow you require, you don't have to define anything.  It's already there and is called `hook'`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r,hook]  & B \\
  C \ar[r,hook'] & D \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can define your own arrows easily as specializations of the predefined arrows shipped with the [TikZ `arrows.meta`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#subsection.16.5) library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,cd}
\tikzset{
  five star/.code = {\pgfsetarrowsstart{Rays[n=5]}},
  spaced barb/.code = {\pgfsetarrowsend{Arc Barb[sep].Arc Barb[]}},
  star and barb/.style = {five star, spaced barb}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r,star and barb]  & B \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well that was surprisingly simple. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, but please next time post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with your question.

Comment: My bad; I won't forget it next time. Also, this simple hint induced a great simplification of my `tikz-cd` syntax in general. I have been using commands like `rightarrowtail`, `twoheadrightarrow`, etc. They are now all replaced by easier commands! Thanks a ton.